Find the value of the integral of the real root of an equation

For $x\ge0$ let $f(x)$ represents the real root of the equation $$y^3+26xy=27$$ Find the value of $$\int_0^1 f^2(x) \ln(f(x)) dx$$

Whenever I see such kind of questions, I instantly think of Lisant's formula but I don't think I can apply that here.
I also tried to do by parts but that too in vain.
I saw that I can factorise the expression as $$26xy=(3-y)(y^2+3y+9)$$
Although idk if it can help me in any way.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

You have $f(x)^3+26 x f(x)=27$. Take the derivatives of both sides w.r.t $x$, solve the resulting quadratic equation in $f$, and see if you can get $f^{2}$ in terms of $f^{\prime}$.

@Medo I did it and $f^2$ can be evaluated in terms of $f'$ but it too much lengthy and complex

Notice that, if $y^3+26xy=27$, then $x=\dfrac{27-y^3}{26y}=g(y)$.
Changing the variable of integration to $y$ we get (using that $g(3)=0$, $g(1)=1$) $$\int_0^1 f^2(x) \ln(f(x)) dx=\int_3^1 (g^{-1}(g(y)))^2 \ln(g^{-1}(g(y)))g'(y)\, dy=$$$$=\int_1^{3}y^2\ln(y)\dfrac{27+2y^3}{26y^2}\,dy=\int_1^{3}\ln(y)\dfrac{27+2y^3}{26}\,dy$$
This last integral is immediate  (integration by parts does the job) and equals $$\dfrac{243\ln(3)-128}{52}\approx2.672$$
This can be checked numerically: see 1 and 2.

Ig 243 should be first....is that a typo? I see it now you changed limits but forgot to add a negative sign...nvm thnx a lot

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad  No, the negative sign cancelled with one that appears at $g'(y)$; it is true that the the $243\ln(3)$ should go first, I edited the answer.
